# Cannot spy on a function when called inside setInterval

Tags: jestjs

`fetchTokens`  is indeed called multiple times while advancing time, as I tried to log the outputs.

But spying on `fetchTokens` does not show that it has been called multiple times.

```
const tokens = await this.fetchTokens();
setInterval(() => {
    this.fetchTokens();
}, 1000);

const fetchTokens() => {
    console.log('nice')
}
```

Jest tests:

```
jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000);
const fetchTokens = jest.spyOn(service, 'fetchTokens');

await service.main();

expect(fetchTokens).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

I can guess that the spy couldn't spy on calls inside the `setInterval` , so how can I achieve this.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. What's `this`? `const fetchTokens() => {` isn't even valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as `setInterval` depends on real time, you should use fake timers to properly mock function inside.

Fake timers will swap out `setInterval()` with an implementation that gets it`s time from the fake clock.

[Reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks)

Like:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers(); // top level of spec

  it('Should pass', async () => {        
    const fetchTokens = jest.spyOn(service, 'fetchTokens');
    await service.main();

    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

    expect(fetchTokens).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
});
```